# Having an issue learning unittest in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
import unittest

def get_formatted_name(first, last):

    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    return full_name.title()

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first_last_name(self):

        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('john', 'smith')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'John Smith')

unittest.main()
```

So I'm still fairly new to Python and this is my first time using `unittest`. I'm trying to test the `get_formatted_name` function using `unittest` but it keeps coming back:

> Ran 0 test in 0.00s
>
> OK

I'm assuming that there's something wrong with my `NamesTestCase` `class`, anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to say _how_ you are invoking `unittest`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my local and it works well

```
~/Documents/Python » python test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

I'm using Python 2.7.14.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using 3.6.2 in Pycharm, and haven't had any issues before.  I switched it to 2.7.13 but it still wasn't running the test.  Just tried it under Pyscripter, same code and it ran the test..  I don't know what's going wrong?